# Doing math with NSExpression using parenthsis

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsexpression

I haven the NSString `@"200 * (1 + (5 / 100))"`,

when I put it into a `NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:myString];`

and `NSLog` `expression` I it returns the string.
When I however call `[[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] doubleValue]` I get a result of `200`.

Can `NSExpression`not handle two sets of parenthesis? Is the another solution with using `NSExpression` - I don't want to use any of the MathLibraries, because I just have very simple math equations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it can handle two sets of brackets, your problem is simply in the types of your values.

When you write `200 * (1 + (5 / 100))` all these values are treated as integers, and integer arithmetic is used. This means that `5 / 100` evaluates to `0` and that's why you get `200` as the result. If it were `5.0 / 100` (notice the decimal point), then you'd be getting the right result, as that division would be treated as a float division.

Comment: Can I force it to always calculate as double? The string is user inputted and they could also enter something like "99/2" which is not supposed to be evaluated as integer division.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not such a way, you'll have to implement some parsing/replacing logic to the string

Comment: ok - thanks... Then I will have to include DDMathParser into my project. Wanted to prevent using 3rd party libraries, but oh well. ;)